# How do I access a user's role using the auth0 R package?

Tags: r, shiny, roles, auth0

I am using the Auth0 R package to add a sign in feature to an R Shiny app (curso-r/auth0). I was wondering how I can access the user's role after the user signs in inside the app, to give different users different experiences. (I'm wondering if there is something similar to the method for getting user credentials, as in the variable 'session$userData$auth0_credentials').

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you been able to create the permission for each users, this should allow you to get access to user credentials from your end. so please try to do this first.